# wordpress add_post_meta more than one key value store

Tags: wordpress, post

WordPress

```
add_action('save_post',function($pid){

   add_post_meta($pid,'country','India');

});
```

on saving post it is creating 3 meta keys/value with country - India,,
i want ti to right now one so that later can add multiple entry for this key,,

Answer (score 3):

Create a Array:

```
add_action('save_post',function($pid){


   $country = array('country_1' => 'India', 'country_2' => 'Cuba', 'country_3' => 'Irlanda'); //Or you can get "get_options('country')" dynamic.

   //Or this:
   //$country = array('India', 'Cuba', 'Irlanda');

   add_post_meta($pid,'country', $country);

});
```

I hope help you.